# How can I use tailwindcss colors in smelte components?

Tags: svelte, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a service with svelte, and I also use smelte and tailwindcss for UI.

I put button component and set a color like this.

```svelte
...
<Button color="text-gray-700">button</Button>
...
```

But color "text-gray-700" wasn't shown.
In the document,

> Color variant, accepts any of the main colors described in Tailwind config

So It seems that I need to write to config all colors that I want to use,but I don't want to write them.
Then,Is there any ways to use tailwindcss color like "text-gray-700" in the smelte component.

Comment: Hi there! Not familiar with svelte but `text-gray-700` generate property for CSS color not color itself. The color name is `gray-700`. Try to write `color="gray-700"` not `text-gray-700`

Answer (score 0):

We don't know where your config setting is problem to use, but you need to check any settings overriding or defined as your `tailwind setup` in your `tailwind.config.js` file.

and other common solution is just try this,

```
// your main css file like "index.css"

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  ...
  // add any your custom utilities
  text-gray-700 {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgba(55, 65, 81, var(--tw-text-opacity));
  },
  text-gray-800 {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgba(55, 65, 81, var(--tw-text-opacity));
  },
  ...
```

If you show your using index.css or tailwind.config.js file, we can provide a more detailed solution.

Answer (score 0):

I confronted the same stuff, here is how I solved it.

1. Make sure you've installed tailwindcss correctly. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/sveltekit
2. In your **tailwind.config.cjs** file, change it like this:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}',
        './node_modules/flowbite-svelte/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}'
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                gray: colors.gray
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        require('flowbite/plugin')
    ],
    darkMode: 'class'
};
```

After this, you should see the gray color.